# join two tables both with MAX() sub queries values using mysql or mariadb

Tags: mysql, join, max, mariadb

I have two tables in a mysql/mariadb db. Both have MAX(history) values to maintain revisions. The tables are joined so `tableB` references `tableA`

I can do a basic look up where searching on `tableB` to get only the latest version of each record and join that back to `tableA`.

tableA

```
|product|value|history|
|alpha  |a    |0      |
|beta   |z    |0      |
|delta  |s    |0      |
```

tableB

```
|type   |product|history|
|blue   |alpha  |0      |
|blue   |beta   |1      |
|green  |alpha  |0      |
|green  |delta  |1      |
```

mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `b`.`type` AS `b_type`,  
  `b`.`product` AS `b_prod`,
  `b`.`history` AS `b_hist`,
  `a`.`value`   AS `a_val`,
  `a`.`history` AS `a_hist`
from `myTable`.`tableB` `b`  
JOIN (
  SELECT type, MAX(history) history
  FROM `myTable`.`tableB`
  GROUP BY type
 ) `tabB` ON `b`.`history` =`tabB`.`history` AND `b`.`type` =`tabB`.`type`
 JOIN `myTable`.`tableA` `a` 
 ON `a`.`product` = `b`.`product`
```

returns

```
|b_type|b_prod|b_hist|a_val|a_hist|
|blue  |beta  |1     |a    |0     |
|green |delta |1     |s    |0     |
```

Now I would like to add a history element to `tableA`

```
|product|value|history|
|alpha  |a    |0      |
|alpha  |b    |1      |
|beta   |z    |0      |
|beta   |y    |1      | 
|delta  |s    |0      |
|delta  |t    |1      |
```

How do I add the second `JOIN` to filter `tableA` results on `MAX(HISTORY)`

```
JOIN (
      SELECT product, MAX(history) history
      FROM `myTable`.`tableA`
      GROUP BY product
     ) `tabA` ON `a`.`history` =`tabA`.`history` AND `a`.`product` 
 =`tabA`.`product`
```

so the returned values would look like

```
|b_type|b_prod|b_hist|a_val|a_hist|
|blue  |beta  |1     |b    |1     |
|green |delta |1     |t    |1     |
```

Comment: @Strawberry, rouge comma removed

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your first query does not produce the result you claim.It produces | blue   | beta   |      1 | z     |      0 |
| green  | delta  |      1 | s     |      0 |